# how to decode sha 256 encoded string using jquery/javascript or angular 2/4?

Tags: javascript, decode, sha256

Using sha256.js plugin I can encode string but how to do the reverse process on client side.I want to decode sha256 encoded string using javascript or jquery plugin or npm package in angular 2/4

Comment: SHA256 is a hashing algorthm. It cannot be decrypted - that's the point.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the suggestion. can you please tell me that how to decrypt sha256 hash encoded  string using crypto js?

Comment: You can't - as I mentioned above SHA256 is for hashing, not encrypting

Comment: @Developer, SHA256 is a one side encryption.

Comment: @Developer, as Rory said SHA256 is hashing algorithm, you cannot reverse it, but the idea if you want to match some string with a SHA256 script you just need to apply the hash on the string you have and then compare the two outputs (As result of hashing is always the same)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't decode hash but compare with another string hashed.
You need an encrypted way like AES, RSA, etc. not hash